# 0-dimensional Hausdorff dimension of a set

Tags: real-analysis, fractals, hausdorff-measure

There is an easy proof to show that for a finite object of any size $H^0(M) = |M|$, its 0-Hausdorff dimension is equal to its size. This is done by covering the set by sufficiently small balls and showing that one needs $|M|$ balls to cover it.

However, I'm asked to state this result in general. So $M$ may be countably infinite or uncountable.

How does one formalize the reasoning for finite objects to arbitrary sized objects? I was told to do it by first proving the case of countable sets and then extend it to unions of countable sets. I was told that this is enough to have it for arbitrary sets. Is this a general pattern in mathematics? Why is it true?

Comment: Thus, you simply want to show that ${\cal H}^0(M)=\infty$ whenever $M$ is an infinite set in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @MarkMcClure essentially yes, how can you formally stablish that. the argument I was given interests me by itself